# SQL: Efficiently calculate maximum concurrently logged-in users in interval based on historical record

Tags: sql, case, query-optimization, informix

I am trying to find a query that finds the true number of maximum concurrent users in an interval based on historical record of user logins (in this case, the interval is daily).

The below query would do the job, except that on a table of size 500k records, the query will take more than 8 hours to complete and eventually be killed before finishing.

```
SELECT  DATE(DBINFO('utc_to_datetime', login_utc)) AS utcDate,
        MAX(NVL(cumeins, 0) - NVL(cumeouts, 0)) AS Concurrent
FROM (
    SELECT  s.login_utc,
            (SELECT count(*)
             FROM root.haglog s2
                WHERE s2.login_utc <= s.login_utc
            ) AS cumeins,
            (SELECT count(*)
             FROM root.haglog s2
                WHERE s2.logout_utc <= s.login_utc
            ) AS cumeouts
    FROM root.haglog s GROUP BY login_utc
) s
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

So the login_utc / logout_utc fields are not indexed, but there is an indexed field available called row_date (simply the date of the record without the time component). I thought to try and utilize this index to speed up the selection process as below, such that we are only comparing against the non-indexed fields in the event the row considered is already the same date (a much smaller subset):

```
SELECT  DATE(DBINFO('utc_to_datetime', login_utc)) AS utcDate,
        MAX(NVL(cumeins, 0) - NVL(cumeouts, 0)) AS Concurrent
FROM (
    SELECT  s.login_utc,
            (SELECT count(*)
             FROM root.haglog s2
                WHERE CASE 
                        WHEN DATE(DBINFO('utc_to_datetime', s2.login_utc)) = s.row_date
                        THEN s2.login_utc <= s.login_utc
                        ELSE 0
                      END
            ) AS cumeins,
            (SELECT count(*)
             FROM root.haglog s2
                WHERE CASE 
                        WHEN DATE(DBINFO('utc_to_datetime', NVL(s2.logout_utc,0))) = s.row_date
                        THEN s2.logout_utc <= s.login_utc
                        ELSE 0
                      END
            ) AS cumeouts
    FROM root.haglog s GROUP BY login_utc, row_date
) s
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

But the case statement as structured above results in a syntax error, likely because it can't pass on the conditional statement logic directly. I am attempting to use case statement here because short traditional circuit evaluation is not guaranteed (otherwise I would just do 'DATE(DBINFO('utc_to_datetime', s2.login_utc)) = s.row_date AND s2.login_utc <= s.login_utc').

Is there a better way reduce computational complexity of original query, and if not, how can I structure query to utilize the row_date index?

### **UPDATE**

I tried out the suggestion by O. Jones and ended up with the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(concurrency) concurrency, row_date FROM (
 SELECT s.row_date, t.t, COUNT(*) concurrency
   FROM root.haglog s
   JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT login_utc t FROM root.haglog s 
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT (NVL(logout_utc, 0) + 1) t FROM root.haglog s
        ) t ON s.login_utc >= t.t AND s.logout_utc < t.t   
  GROUP BY s.row_date, t.t 
) a GROUP BY row_date ORDER BY row_date ASC
```

This query did run fast, but it only returned 7 results (dataset is 500k):

```
concurrency row_date
----------- ---------- 
          1 2018-05-04
          1 2018-06-05
          1 2018-06-26
          1 2018-07-10
          1 2018-08-10
          1 2018-09-10
          1 2018-09-19
```

Here would be some sample data (no, there is not actually user that has been logged in since May):

```
row_date   seq_num    logid   login_utc  logout_utc logout_date 
---------- ---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ----------- 
2018-05-02 1525229404 1201111 1525247404 1525253897 2018-05-02  
2018-05-02 1525229463 1201112 1525247463 1525255395 2018-05-02  
2018-05-02 1525230080 1011111 1525248080 1525266019 2018-05-02  
2018-05-02 1525231420 1211111 1525249420 NULL       NULL
```

The schema would be covered here: https://downloads.avaya.com/elmodocs2/contact_center/r3v11/780701_1/780701_1.pdf

### **UPDATE 2**

For both my original query and the one suggested in answer by O. Jones, I output the relevant columns into a temp table, made indices on all relationships, and still no go. The query runs for a couple hours then gets killed at the server (the client still thinks its running). At this point if I could modify a server execution time property so that it can just run until it completes, that would be good....

Comment: Right, I have tried 'f' for the ELSE clause of the CASE statement and even a true comparison that will always result in false (such as '0 is null') but that won't improve matters. Clearly I can't use the CASE statement as structured.

Comment: Well, I deleted my comment after I realized you were aware of the shortcoming. Are you able to use multiple queries, temp tables etc?

Comment: I can't add procedures or modify schema, but should be able to run multiple queries.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: When creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) for an SQL question, it really helps to have a minimal schema for each relevant table, and a small amount of data for each table, and the desired results for the sample data, and the actual results.  You've identified the DBMS, which is also important information for SQL questions, but you've not given the version of Informix that you're using.  It may not matter much if you're using 12.10 (but it could help to know whether it's 12.10.FC1 or 12.10.FC12), but is more important if you're using 11.70 (or, perish the thought, an even older version of Informix).

Comment: Your comment about "the interval is daily" is also not clear.  With what precision are the login and logout times recorded?  Are you seeking to find the maximum concurrent usage during each 24-hour interval (aligned on times in UTC)?  Just checking: if someone logged in on 2018-10-01 and didn't log out until 2018-10-05, they are counted as logged in all the time on 2nd, 3rd and 4th October as well as the relevant part of 1st and 5th? (Funnier things have been known!) . If someone logs in at 23:50 on 2nd and logs out at 00:10 on 3rd, they count towards concurrent count on both 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: Your table schema might be as simple as `CREATE TABLE root.haglog(user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, login_utc DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL, logout_utc DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND {NOT NULL}, PRIMARY KEY(user_id, login_utc));`.  There might be some relatively complex constraints to add, such that the user cannot have multiple concurrent logins — or maybe they can be logged in multiple times at once and there is some other column that needs to be part of the primary key, such as a session ID.  (Generally, you should avoid creating tables as `root` or as `informix` — but that's a separate discussion.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The precision of login_utc/logout_utc is down to the second (those fields are integers storing epoch seconds). So for every login event recorded, we evaluate all the other users logged into the system at that time to determine concurrency. Then we find the max value observed in each day.

Perish your thoughts: "IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC9". Not much I can do about that, this is a vendor system (Avaya CMS R17). The schema would be covered in here (I will provide data later): https://downloads.avaya.com/elmodocs2/contact_center/r3v11/780701_1/780701_1.pdf

Comment: Also, no worries about multiple logins at once -- the system does not allow this (even if it did, it wouldn't impact our definition of concurrency).

Comment: Sometimes, new indexes are needed to run new queries. That's not uncommon in the world of databases.

Comment: @O.Jones, I guess, and that is the easy way out, but unfortunately it is not an option in this case. I am also struck by the fact that the row_date IS indexed, and so we only need to compare against one day's worth of unindexed records (those for which the row_date is the same as what's compared against). So if my CASE logic inside the WHERE statement could work in my original post above, I know this would be solvable before the server kills the query. I just can't figure out how to formulate the where such that short circuit evaluation could be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the maximum concurrent logins, and you have the login_utc and logout_utc time.  That is, if you draw those time intervals on a timeline, you're looking for the maximum number of overlaps.

Sorry, I don't know how Informix adds one second to a datestamp column. So I used `+ INTERVAL 1 SEC`.

So, start by getting all the distinct timepoints on the timeline

```
            SELECT DISTINCT s.login_utc t FROM root.haglog s
              WHERE row_date >= <<<start date of query>>>
                AND row_date < <<<day after end date of query >>>
            UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT s.logout_utc + INTERVAL 1 SEC t FROM root.haglog s
              WHERE row_date >= <<<start date of query>>>
                AND row_date < <<<day after end date of query >>>
```

Now use that to count overlaps at each time point.

```
     SELECT s.row_date. t.t, COUNT(*) concurrency
       FROM root.haglog s
       JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT s.login_utc t FROM root.haglog s
              WHERE row_date >= <<<start date of query>>>
                AND row_date < <<<day after end date of query >>>
            UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT s.logout_utc + INTERVAL 1 SEC t FROM root.haglog s
              WHERE row_date >= <<<start date of query>>>
                AND row_date < <<<day after end date of query >>>
            ) t ON s.login_utc >= t.t AND s.logout_utc < t.t    
      WHERE row_date >= <<<start date of query>>>
        AND row_date < <<<day after end date of query >>>
      GROUP BY s.row_date, t.t
```

That gives you your concurrency at each time t. You can then do this to get the concurrency for each day

```
       SELECT MAX(concurrency) concurrency, row_date
         FROM ( all that stuff ^^^^ ) a
        GROUP BY row_date
```

This filters on `row_date` to have your index help reduce the number of rows to grind.

If performance is terrible you could put the `t.t` resultset into a temp table and index it.  Or you can do what's needed to index at least one of `login_utc` and `logout_utc`.

Comment: So I have a different query that segments based upon an input row_date. But the requirement is to have the query provide a grouping based on *all* available dates (this would result in about 6 months worth of days, or around 180 results returned). Otherwise I would have to look at running this query 180 times as the historical record is constantly rolling.

Comment: OK. Take out the `WHERE row_date ...` stuff then.

Comment: The basic idea of how to add a second to a DATETIME value is correct; there is room to improve the notation.  You could use `+ 1 UNITS SECOND` or `INTERVAL(1) SECOND TO SECOND` (where the `TO SECOND` is annoying and verbose, so people often use the alternative).

Comment: @O.Jones I'm not sure the logic behind "you're looking for the maximum number of overlaps" is correct. At the very least, the join condition appears flawed -- "ON s.login_utc >= t.t AND s.logout_utc < t.t " would seem to measure events where the login and the logout basically happen at the same time. Because of your adding one second to the logout interval, this does actually happen 7 times in the data. But that's all your query returns -- 7 results (all with concurrency of 1).

Comment: I tried modifying the join statement to "s.login_utc >= t.t AND t.t < s.logout_utc " and that query ended up running for over 8 hours until it got killed as well. Again the DB size is only 500k records. I can try running it with a temp table.

Comment: I output the relevant columns into temp table, made indices on all relationships, and still no go. For both my original query and your modified one... The query runs for a couple hours then gets killed at the server (the client still thinks its running). At this point if I could modify a server execution time property so that it can just run until it completes, that would be good....